# Calculate height and show ViewMore Content based on list items content in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dynamic array which is coming from the server and i need to set viewMore link when the element height is greater than certain height.
This viewMore content need to be shown like this.

```
<div id={`_message_detail_list${id}`}>
      <ul style={{ "max-height":  valListMaxHeight }}>{listItems}</ul>
      <div>
        {viewMoreText (here i need to add another condition to check height of ul is greater than some threshold)  && (
          <div>
            <a
              id={`_primaryAction_${id}`}
              href="#"
              data-key={id}
              onClick={this.handleClick}>
              {viewMoreText}
            </a>
          </div>
```

is it possible to calculate the height and show another element based on this height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in comibination with `clientHeight` like so:

```
const ulElementRef = useRef(null);

const ulHeight = elementRef.current?.clientHeight;

//...

<ul ref={ulElementRef} style={{ "max-height":  valListMaxHeight }}>{listItems}</ul>
```

Then you can use `ulHeight` for your condition.

Comment: I am using class component and these ui i will render when i get props. So what can i use instead of useref ()